# \cline equivalent that allows `(lr)` trim on either side

Tags: tables, booktabs, cline

I am looking for the equivalent of `\cline{1-1}` that does not affect the vertical spacing, but with the option to be able to apply a trim such as `(lr)` that `\cmidrule` allows.

The MWE below produces:

[image]

I would like the third table to align vertically with the first two but with the short "`\cmidrule(lr){1-1}`" equivalent horizontal line.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \cline{1-1}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But why?  Do you have tables next to each other where one uses hline or cline, and the other uses cmidrule?  Or are you wanting to remove a bit of vertical space from around the cmidrule?

Comment: @Teepeemm: Several reasons: 1. My table barely fits on a page, so don't want to add additional vertical space. My first column is a label for two rows of data. This rule in the first column would serve as a clear divider that the first column is a `\multirow` label.  The MWE is not illutrative of my actual use case, but to make it easier to see/test the desired outcome.

Comment: use cmidrul but set the vertical space (to 0pt for example)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is that a built in option? Will look into it.

Comment: all booktabs rules have \aboverulesep and\belowrulesep so you can set that to 0 then use \addinespace where you want to add some eg around a toprule or ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yep, just found thise two. Now to figure out how to package them into a macro so that they are not global settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting David Carlisle's ideas in to practise, by adding two new dimensions `\abovecrulesep` and `\belowcrulesep` for `\cmidrule`s, gives

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newdimen\abovecrulesep
\newdimen\belowcrulesep
\abovecrulesep=0pt
\belowcrulesep=0pt
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@@cmidrule}{\aboverulesep}{\abovecrulesep}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@xcmidrule}{\belowrulesep}{\belowcrulesep}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \cline{1-1}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

To provide a new command whilst keeping the old version of `\cmidrule` one can do the following

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newdimen\myaboverulesep
\newdimen\mybelowrulesep
\newdimen\mycmidrulewidth
\myaboverulesep=0pt
\mybelowrulesep=0pt
\mycmidrulewidth=\cmidrulewidth

\makeatletter
\def\mycmidrule{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \@ifnextchar[{\@mycmidrule}{\@mycmidrule[\mycmidrulewidth]}}
\def\@mycmidrule[#1]{\@ifnextchar({\@@mycmidrule[#1]}{\@@mycmidrule[#1]()}}
\def\@@mycmidrule[#1](#2)#3{\@@@mycmidrule[#3]{#1}{#2}}
\let\@@@mycmidrule\@@@cmidrule
\let\@myxcmidrule\@xcmidrule
\patchcmd{\@@@mycmidrule}{\aboverulesep}{\myaboverulesep}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@@@mycmidrule}{\@xcmidrule}{\@myxcmidrule}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@myxcmidrule}{\belowrulesep}{\mybelowrulesep}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \cline{1-1}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \mycmidrule(lr){1-1}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The three `\def`s are copies of the internal `\cmidrule` commands that refer to `\my...` versions instead.  They deal with argument parsing for `\cmidrule` and are so short it is easy to copy and modify the code.  We then copy the other two internal commands from `\cmidrule` with `\let` and patch them to use our new commands and parameters.  These definitions are longer, so patching is shorter than rewriting.

Answer (score 5):

It is easier to use `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrInner{rowsep=1pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tblr}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
  \begin{tblr}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \cline{1-1}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
  \begin{tblr}{ l c r }
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{1-1}
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry can't test this yet as it needs an update to the TeXLive 2021 packages.